# How to exclude .DS_Store from file count?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get the file count in a given directoy using python, but I'd like to exclude `.DS_Store` files.

How can that be done?

`count = len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR)])`

Comment: You should probably exclude all "hidden" files - `if not name.startswith('.')`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes, post an answer and ill accept it.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, the answers you already have tell you how to include a conditional filter within a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
count = len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if name != ".DS_Store"])
```

Or to exclude all hidden files, like [jonrsharpe suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943736/how-to-exclude-ds-store-from-file-count/31943798#comment51797525_31943736):

```
count = len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if name.startswith(".")])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `if` within your list comprehension :

```
count = len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if name !='.DS_Store'])
```

Or if you don't want a specific format you can use `str.endswith` :

```
count = len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if if not name.endswith('DS_Store')])
```